# Test app on a jailbreak iPhone

Tags: iphone, testing, jailbreak, iphone-developer-program

I registered to Apple Developer program and paid 99$. 
Now I want to test my application on different iPhones. My friend has jailbreak iPhone so i wanted to know if I can use it to test the application.
1. Is that okay with Apple? i mean is it a violation of the developer program terms?
2. Can it undo the jailbreak on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this question is off topic, I'll answer it.

1. yes you can test apps on this device, Apple could know that you are testing on a jailbroke device by it UDID. They will not close your account for that.
2. No It will not undo the jailbreak unless you upgrade the devices OS via Xcode. Other which it's just like installing any other app.